# Search a meta field for a value in all posts

Tags: customization, query, search

I want to search a meta field for a value in all posts.

Code below shows what I want to accomplish (I'm a WP and PHP beginner and can't manage to make it work by myself). If in meta field "`voted_IP`" there's value `$ip` (current user ip) then echo something, else echo something else.

I need to search in all posts, not just current, so I can't use `get_post_meta`. I found somewhere that I can make it work with query but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'meta_key' => 'voted_IP', 
    'meta_value' => $ip
) );
if ($query == $ip) {
    echo 'one';
} else {
    echo 'two';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WP_Query` will return a `WP_Query` object. An object will never match the string `$ip` that you are comparing it to. What you need to be doing is checking whether results were returned, which you can do by checking the `found_posts` property:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_key' => 'voted_IP', 
    'meta_value' => $ip
) );
if (0 !== $query->found_posts) {
    echo 'one';
} else {
    echo 'two';
}
```

Or you can use the `WP_Query` method `have_posts`:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_key' => 'voted_IP', 
    'meta_value' => $ip
) );
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    echo 'one';
} else {
    echo 'two';
}
```

Note that I added an `ignore_sticky_posts` condition. You need that to make this work reliably

By default the query will check for published posts, if you need other post types or post statuses you will need to add more conditions.